# Google maps key with different google play account

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play, account

i want to publish an Android application with my google account using (inside the application) a google maps key of another google account.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps API key is tied to ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup)):

- The certificate that you signed your release app with
- The package of your app

So, yes, you can use one account to generate the API key and another to upload the app to the Play Store.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't works. If i create a key with the same account where i will publish my app, it works. If i create the same key with the same sha1 and the same package name but with another account, it'doesn't.

Comment: b: Authentication failed on the server.
E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
E/Google Maps Android API: Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
E/Google Maps Android API: Ensure that the following Android Key exists: "XXX"
Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): "SHA1";"PACKAGE_NAME"

Comment: I have two account with the same couple of {package_name - sha1} in google maps developer. Only the one where i publish the app works.

Comment: Are you using any paid plan? I can't find any reference in the documentation and I had a similar use case some time ago (maybe the behaviour has changed :S)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your help, i found that android API must be enabled from backend. The second account was not set up properly, sorry for the loss of time!
I share the link where enable google map api for android (because for iOS is not necessary) :
[Google maps api - android backend](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/maps_android_backend/)

Thanks again!